# Is there a way to find the cause of random spikes in response time on Heroku (Ruby on Rails app)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, analytics

On my Ruby on Rails Heroku app, I'm getting random spikes in response time upwards of 30-40 seconds. Obviously this is unacceptable for a web app. But I'm not seeing correlating spikes in throughput. Is there a gem or app I can use to find out what is causing these spikes?

[image: Heroku Metrics]

Comment: Something like NewRelic can give you info on problematic or long queries / transactions

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Scout](https://scoutapp.com/) or [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/) which will show you timings for each of your requests. They will also give you a breakdown of how much time was spent in various parts of the request lifecycle like database querying and rendering. This might help you narrow down which of your routes might be really expensive in terms of memory or inefficient database queries.

Look out for excessive ActiveRecord object instantiations, or performing work such as image uploads/manipulations on the web process. These types of operations are best offloaded to a background worker like ActiveJob or Sidekiq.

Answer (score 0):

[New Relic](https://newrelic.com/) includes [transaction traces](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/transactions/transaction-traces/introduction-transaction-traces) that can provide a very detailed view of what's happening in a request.

Each transaction trace will include a high level overview of the call stack:

[image: Summary]

As well as a detailed trace showing exactly where time is being spent:

[image: Details]

Traces are created automatically for the slowest requests, but you can also have New Relic [create custom traces for key transactions](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/transactions/transaction-traces/configure-transaction-traces#key-txns).